# return claim without requiring role quarkus

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

I have a keycloak + quarkus setup running in docker compose but I'm running into a strange issue.

Authentication and authorization works fine but when I return the username it is empty unless I require a role.

In other words, when my endpoint requires a role everything works fine and I get the users username returned in the response, however if I remove the rolesrequired annotation the response is empty.

Is it possible to get the username without a rolesrequired annotation somehow?

This works:

```
@GET
@Path('me')
@RolesRequired('user')
public User me() {
    return new User(identity);
}
```

This doesn't work (it returns username: '')

```
@GET
@Path('me')
public User me() {
    return new User(identity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quarkus OIDC extension does not handle authentication token for resouce method that not secured (with out @RolesAllowed annotation) and User Identity is anonymous

Use @Authenticated instead @RolesAllowed annotation for methods when you want to get UserIdentity.